# Assembly jmp memory expression

Tags: assembly, gdb, disassembly

Im dissasembling something for a project, and I encountered with the following line

```
jmp *0x80498c0(,%eax,4)
```

What exactly is that jump instruction trying to do?
This is in a gdb environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an indirect jump.

The instruction calculates the location `[0x80498c0 + eax*4]`, loads the value stored there and jumps to the address stored at this location.

This kind of code is quite common seen in jumptables, often after a C `switch` instruction or equivalent.

Edit: The `*` is specific to the AT&T syntax. It's a mnemonic for *dereference*, like in C. It is needed in the case the part in the braces is missing - `jmp 0x80498c0` would just jump to this address, where `jmp *0x80498c0` jumps to the target of the pointer stored in 0x80498c0.

Answer (score 3):

see the *Referencing memory:*  section [here](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/brennan/brennan_att_inline_djgpp.html)
A 32-bit addressing can be seen as follows (AT&T format)

> immed32(basepointer,indexpointer,indexscale)

This is translated as the value at address given by

> immed32 + basepointer + indexpointer * indexscale

For example, to address a[i] where "a" is an array of integers, you could write

> (%eax, %ebx, 4)

such that eax register holds the base pointer of a and ebx has the index i.

Comment: [Bare links are not real answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/102937)  Can you summarize the portion of the page that you linked to that applies to the OP's question, in your answer here?

Comment: I kind of understand now, but what does the asterisk ( * ) before the Immediate value means?